# Mixing C and C++, raw pointers and (boost) shared pointers

Tags: c++, c, boost, dictionary, shared-ptr

I am working in C++ with some legacy C code.

I have a data structure that (during initialisation), makes a copy of the structure pointed to a ptr passed to its initialisation pointer.

Here is a simplification of what I am trying to do - hopefully, no important detail has been lost in the "simplification":

```
/* C code */

typedef struct MyData
{
   double * elems;
   unsigned int len;   
};

int NEW_mydata(MyData* data, unsigned int len)
{
    // no error checking
    data->elems = (double *)calloc(len, sizeof(double)); 
    return 0;
}

typedef struct Foo
{
   MyData data data_;
};


void InitFoo(Foo * foo, const MyData * the_data)
{
   //alloc mem etc ... then assign the STRUCTURE
   foo.data_ = *thedata ;
}


C++ code
-------------
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyData> MyDataPtr;
typedef std::map<std::string, MyDataPtr> Datamap;

class FooWrapper
{
public:
   FooWrapper(const std::string& key) {
       MyDataPtr mdp = dmap[key];
       InitFoo(&m_foo, const_cast<MyData*>((*mdp.get())));
   }

   ~FooWrapper();

   double get_element(unsigned int index ) const {
      return m_foo.elems[index];
   }

private:
   // non copyable, non-assignable
   FooWrapper(const FooWrapper&);
   FooWrapper& operator= (const FooWrapper&);

   Foo m_foo;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

   MyData data1, data2;
   Datamap dmap;

   NEW_mydata(&data1, 10);
   data1->elems[0] = static_cast<double>(22/7);

   NEW_mydata(&data2, 42);
   data2->elems[0] = static_cast<double>(13/21);

   boost::shared_ptr d1(&data1), d2(&data2);

   dmap["data1"] = d1;
   dmap["data2"] = d2;

   FooWrapper fw("data1");


   //expect 22/7, get something else (random number?)
   double ret fw.get_element(0);    
}
```

Essentially, what I want to know is this:

Is there any reason why the data retrieved from the map is different from the one stored in the map?

Comment: 22/7 is integer division, and MyData (and therefore also Foo) can't be safely copied since it contains a pointer to heap memory.

Comment: It would be helpful if your example was syntactically correct and actually compiled.

Comment: First, rewrite this to be legal code.  We can only guess at anything when we get what you say is a simplification, and which doesn't show the behavior you've seen because it doesn't have any behavior at all.  Second, tell us what you got out.  "something else (random number?)" tells us precisely nothing useful.  If it's the same output for each of your runs, say so, and tell us what it is.  If it isn't, say so, and list a few values.  If you want highly competent programmers to answer your questions without any compensation, meet us halfway at least.

Comment: @David Thornley: "If you want highly competent programmers to answer your questions without any compensation, meet us halfway at least" Fair point. I apologize for not given enough to go ... I have a lot of balls in the air at the moment. I'll ponder it some more, and if I still can't figure it out, I will spend some time to write a snippet that compiles and demonstrates the problem. Thanks

Comment: Your code got mangled in the reduction (butthanks anyway for trying ;)): You are inserting into local variable `dmap`, and try to pull from local `fw`, which doesn't know anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/) of map to insert element will erase the previous data stored at the same key, try using [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/) instead.
Same deal with getting data from map, operator[] will create an element if your Key is not stored, try using [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) instead.

Also `const_cast<MyData*>((*mdp.get()))` will cast a MyData in Mydata*, `const_cast<MyData*>(mdp.get())` will be good ...